# Laravel\Vue - ajax file upload not working on the production server

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, upload, vue.js

I have a component where I am uploading a video file, everything works fine on my local machine, and it used to work fine on the production server, **Namechap** is where I host the project, until only recently I have done some work and made changes, that I saw it doesn't work on the production server anymore.

I am using **Vue v. 1.0.28**, and this is the upload component, where in the `fileInputChange()` method I am posting form data, to the `/upload` endpoint, which on the production server for some reason I can't read in the backend:

```
<template>
  <div class="card-content col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <div v-if="!uploading">
          <div class="col-md-12 Image-input__input-wrapper">
              Upload video
              <input type="file" name="video" id="video" @change="fileInputChange" class="Image-input__input" accept="video/*">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="alert alert-danger video-upload-alert" v-if="failed">Something went wrong. Please check the video format and try again. If you need any help please contact our <a>support service.</a></div>

      <div id="video-form">
          <div class="alert alert-info" v-if="uploading && !failed && !uploadingComplete">
              Please do not navigate away from this page, until the video has finished uploading. Your video will be available at <a href="{{ $root.url }}/videos/{{ uid }}" target="_blank">{{ $root.url }}/videos/{{ uid }}</a>, once uploaded.
          </div>

          <div class="alert alert-success" v-if="uploading && !failed && uploadingComplete">
              Upload complete. Video is now processing. <a href="/videos">Go to your videos</a>.
          </div>

          <div class="progress" v-if="uploading && !failed && !uploadingComplete">
              <div class="progress-bar" v-bind:style="{ width: fileProgress + '%' }"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="title">
              </div>
              <!--
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <label for="visibility" class="control-label">Visibility</label>
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="visibility">
                      <option value="private">Private</option>
                      <option value="unlisted">Unlisted</option>
                      <option value="public">Public</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              -->
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" v-model="description"></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" @click.prevent="update">Save</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <span class="help-block pull-right">{{ saveStatus }}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    function initialState (){
        return {
            uid: null,
            uploading: false,
            uploadingComplete: false,
            failed: false,
            title: null,
            link: null,
            description: null,
            visibility: 'private',
            saveStatus: null,
            fileProgress: 0
        }
    }
    export default {
        data: function (){
            return initialState();
        },
        methods: {
            fileInputChange() {
                this.uploading = true;
                this.failed = false;

                this.file = document.getElementById('video').files[0];

                var isVideo = this.isVideo(this.file.name.split('.').pop());

                if (isVideo) {
                  this.store().then(() => {
                      var form = new FormData();

                      form.append('video', this.file);
                      form.append('uid', this.uid);

                      this.$http.post('/upload', form, {
                          progress: (e) => {
                              if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                  this.updateProgress(e)
                              }
                          }
                      }).then(() => {
                          this.uploadingComplete = true
                          this.uploading = false
                      }, () => {
                          this.failed = true
                          this.uploading = false
                      });
                  }, () => {
                      this.failed = true
                      this.uploading = false
                  })
                }
                else {
                  this.failed = true
                  this.uploading = false
                }
            },
            isVideo(extension) {
                switch (extension.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'm4v':
                case 'avi':
                case 'mpg':
                case 'mp4':
                case 'mp3':
                case 'mov':
                case 'wmv':
                case 'flv':
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            store() {
                return this.$http.post('/videos', {
                    title: this.title,
                    description: this.description,
                    visibility: this.visibility,
                    extension: this.file.name.split('.').pop()
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.uid = response.json().data.uid;
                });
            },
            update() {
                this.saveStatus = 'Saving changes.';

                return this.$http.put('/videos/' + this.uid, {
                    link: this.link,
                    title: this.title,
                    description: this.description,
                    visibility: this.visibility
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.saveStatus = 'Changes saved.';

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.saveStatus = null
                    }, 3000)
                }, () => {
                    this.saveStatus = 'Failed to save changes.';
                });
            },
            updateProgress(e) {
                e.percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                this.fileProgress = e.percent;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that on upload in my controller in the store function the request object is empty on the production server, which I got when I did `dd($request->all())`. Then it fails to find the video, in the network inspector I get a `404` error, which is returned by `firstOrFail()` method, because it can't find the `Video model`, since it is missing `$request->uid`.

> No query results for model [App\Video].

This is the controller:

```
class VideoUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('video.upload');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $player = $request->user()->player()->first();

      $video = $player->videos()->where('uid', $request->uid)->firstOrFail();

      $request->file('video')->move(storage_path() . '/uploads', $video->video_filename);

      $this->dispatch(new UploadVideo(
          $video->video_filename
      ));

      return response()->json(null, 200);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is going on, since on inspecting the network tab in the console I am sending a request payload that looks like this:

> ------WebKitFormBoundarywNIkEqplUzfumo0A Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video"; filename="Football Match Play.mp4" Content-Type: video/mp4
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarywNIkEqplUzfumo0A Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uid"
>
> 159920a7878cb2
>   ------WebKitFormBoundarywNIkEqplUzfumo0A--

It is really frustrating since I have no idea how to fix this, when everything is fine on my local machine, not sure what is wrong on the production server and how to fix it?

**Update**

It started working again on its own, since I have created a ticket in the Namecheap support service, all of sudden after one day, it started working again, I haven't done any changes, and on asking the Namecheap support I have got an answer from them that they haven't done any changes either, so I have no idea what went wrong, which is still a bit frustrating since I would like to avoid that in the future, but at least everything is working now again as it should.

Comment: Take a look in your browser's network inspector. I'd bet there's a validation error that's causing a 422 response or a 302 redirect.

Comment: No, there is not a validation error, like I said, I have the same scripts and it works on the local machine

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not a validation error. Have you checked what's happening in the network inspector? Do you see the file in the request, and do you see a response code you're expecting?

Comment: I have checked the $request that I am getting in the controller method, and the if do ```$request->all()``` I get the empty object

Comment: For the **third time**, *have you checked what's happening in the network inspector?*

Comment: yes, in the network inspector I get an error, of 404, because it can't find the Video model, and that is because of the firstOrFail method, which is not finding anything because of the missing $request->uid

Comment: When `$request->all()` returns an empty object you have to check first WHY it did this. Have you checked the upload with the same video so there are no errors because of the type or size ot it?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that already, same video goes through locally, but not on the server, no errors are being thrown, and no validation errors for that matter.

Comment: @Leff did you debug it? Just insert `var_dump($request->uid)` before `firstOrFail` line. You exposed a large bounty but didn't a simple debug?

Comment: yes, I did, I though I made myself clear when I said I got an empty object in my controller

Comment: Please paste your routes.

Comment: document.getElementById('video').src;

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's `$request->all()` method only pulls from the input, thus in the `store()` method of `VideoUploadController` `$request->all()` return empty object.

In your script, it calls `this.store()` after checked the `isVideo` is true while file changes. As a result, there isn't a `uid` parameter or `video` parameter.

Comment: If I do ```$request->all()``` locally I get a ```uid``` and a ```file```

Comment: I think something is wrong with your webserver configuration. Which server do you use? Nginx or Apache?